# Citrus TestNG test Data Provider Mismatch

Tags: citrus-framework

I get an exception - data provider mismatch when trying to get citrus context with a data provider

This is the test and the data provider

```
 @DataProvider(name = "todoDataProvider")
  public Object[][] todoDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new String[] {"todo1", "Description: todo1"},
      new String[] {"todo2", "Description: todo2"},
      new String[] {"todo3", "Description: todo3"}
    };
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "todoDataProvider")
  @CitrusTest
  @Parameters({"name", "description", "context"})
  public void testProvider(
      String name, String description, @CitrusResource @Optional TestContext context) {

    variable("todoId", "citrus:randomUUID()");
    //   this.name(todoName);
    echo(name);
  }
```

> org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
>   Data provider mismatch
>   Method: testProvider([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=com.consol.citrus.context.TestContext, declaredAnnotations=[@com.consol.citrus.annotations.CitrusResource(), @org.testng.annotations.Optional(value=null)]}])
>   Arguments: [(java.lang.String)todo1,(java.lang.String)Description: todo1]
>       at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:49)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.injectParameters(Invoker.java:1293)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1187)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 1):

The citrus parameters seem to get injected into the data provider parameters that are passed, so the data provider needs to include space for the citrus parameters.

found
https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/commit/952204eaacf672677a01cc66f3385f64cd08f8d4
which had a fix for passing citrus variables with data provider, but more importantly/useful to me, unit tests. So played with unit tests and looks like the null is required in the data provider for each citrus variable to be injected/passed.

```
 @DataProvider(name = "todoDataProvider")
  public Object[][] todoDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new String[] {"todo1", "Description: todo1", null},
      new String[] {"todo2", "Description: todo2", null},
      new String[] {"todo3", "Description: todo3", null}
    };
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "todoDataProvider")
  @CitrusTest
  @Parameters({"name", "description", "context"})
  public void testProvider(
      String name, String description, @CitrusResource @Optional TestContext context) {

    variable("todoId", "citrus:randomUUID()");
    //   this.name(todoName);
    echo(name);
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "testData")
  @Parameters({"data", "temp", "runner", "context"})
  @CitrusTest
  public void injectResourceRunnerCombinedWithParameter(
      String data,
      String test,
      @CitrusResource TestRunner testRunner,
      @CitrusResource TestContext context) {
    final String number = Functions.randomNumber(10L, context);
    context.setVariable("message", "Injection worked!");

    testRunner.echo("${message}");
    testRunner.echo("${data}");
    testRunner.createVariable("random", number);

    testRunner.run(
        new AbstractTestAction() {
          @Override
          public void doExecute(TestContext context) {
            Assert.assertEquals(context.getVariable("random"), number);
          }
        });
  }

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] testData() {

    return new Object[][] {{"hello", "test", null, null}, {"bye", "test", null, null}};
  }
```